# 16bit PWM beyond audible range

Tags: arduino, pwm, dac, servo

I need to precisely control (the position of) a small 3 phase servo motor with a microcontroller without breaking the bank. My research and confidence in my own skills has led me to something like an Arduino driving a L6234, but getting 16 bits of PWM resolution (with say, ATmega32U4 or Teensy) gives me a PWM frequency of no more than a couple of kHz (I understand why this has to be so.)

On the other hand, from what I've been reading, I can use a 4 channel 16 bit DAC like the LTC2654 in conjunction with an analog PWM like the LTC6992 and a crystal oscillator to generate very high frequency, high resolution PWM. For the components listed I would probably need a precision voltage reference too. The PWM would then go to the H bridge, possibly get filtered and then passed to the motor.

I also see that there are DACs with internal voltage reference but they are single channel, which increases my component count.

Could anyone tell me where this will go wrong and what I can improve? Suggestions for other components welcome too.

Edit:
I see the L6234 has a maximum switching frequency of 50 kHz, which is fine for me, but I'm not sure if the PWM chip can perate below 62.5 kHz. Maybe coffee will fix that.

Comment: 16 bits corresponds to 0.005° resolution, looks like overkill...

Comment: bobflux, it's for a linear motor actually, so not really. But I don't expect to get all 16 bits worth of accuracy, though it would be nice. I'm concerned that the PWMs resolution might limit me to less.

Comment: Are you really sure you need to be able to set the PWM dutycycle in 65536 steps? What manner of servo motor is that, that hath such precision?

Comment: Pole pair pitch is 25mm, so 65536 steps is roughly 0.4um, but with nonlinearity and noise limits 2um would be respectable. My encoder will give me 0.5um resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use fractional-N, aka Delta Sigma?

Let's say you start from a 16 MHz clock on an Arduino, and you generate an integer part of perhaps 32 or 64, depending on how fast you can write the routine to calculate the new numbers. I'd say getting it done in 64 cycles is definitely possible even in lazy C, 32 may take some C subtly or assembler skill, but should be possible.

Assuming a 64 cycle integer part, that would update at 16 MHz / 64 = 250 kHz. This would be the basic PWM frequency. You would take the 16 bit word you want to program, take the top 6 MSBs, and that's the basic duty cycle you would feed to the PWM hardware.

Now you need to handle the 10 bit fractional part. Using only integer arithmetic, it's possible to successively sum the fraction part to generate cycle by cycle adjustments on the fly to the integer part. The calculation function has to complete getting the next number, and writing it into the PWM hardware each PWM cycle.

One variable you have is the order of correction that's used. First order correction looks fairly comprehensible to the layman. Let's say the fractional part is 0.25, and the integer is 10. The algorithm would generate the following sequence of integers to the PWM hardware, each cycle taking a new number, 10, 10, 10, 11, 10 ... etc. On average, the duty cycle is 10.25. Note that we have a periodicity now at 250 kHz/4. If the fractional part was 0.01, then that low frequency periodicity would be down at 2.5 kHz. Although that's audio, it's very much attenuated from what would be the case if the PWM ran at 16 M/ 65k = 244 Hz with 16 bits. However, we rarely use first order for this reason.

Second order correction dithers the integer by up to +2 and -1, in an apparently pseudo-random sequence, which tends to break up that low frequency periodicity into broadband noise. Third order dithers by up to +4 and -3. While the correction with higher orders gets better, the increasing amounts of dither eat into our dynamic range. It turns out there's rarely any benefit to going to higher than third order for most applications with this type of fractional-N encoder.

For a full description of how to code it, see [this patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4609881A/en). It's actually written for a frequency synthesiser, but the maths stays exactly the same. It's long expired, so there's nothing legal to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough response. If I understand correctly, if we look at the effect of the LSB in the input,  it would cause a low frequency modulation of the 250 kHz carrier at 244 Hz, the next bit at 488 Hz, etc. The goal now is to move that low frequency upwards with more tricks. I'm going deep down a rabbit hole now to understand how this works. My concern is that there's no free lunch at the end, but time will tell. Thank you.

Comment: @lionelbrits It doesn't move the low frequency upwards in frequency as such, it turns it into a whole swathe of frequencies, all the big amplitude ones appear at high frequencies, and some very tiny ones still occur at low frequencies. In a synthesiser, 3rd order correction with a 1000:1 ratio between the 'PWM rate' and the top of the filter band works 'perfectly', that is other defects limit the performance. We don't have the luxury of that large ratio here, so it's not going to work as perfectly, but will outperform integer 16 bit by a long way, maybe well enough, and still use the arduino.

Comment: It occurs to me that rather than tie up the microcontroller with some carefully crafted bit banging, there ought to be an inexpensive part that will take a 16 bit word over SPI or such and output the appropriate bitstream, like a 1 bit DAC, but without the analog filter at the end. Unfortunately I don't know what to search for or if such a component even exists. Perhaps a better description would be a 16 bit Sigma Delta encoder.

Comment: @lionelbrits It's such a niche application there's no market for it, especially not since it can be cooked up with the cheapest available MCU or FPGA module. When John and I developed that system I linked to, back in 1980, implementation was painful. We had to buy an ASIC development system, and make our own ASIC. We toyed with the idea of making a more comprehensive ASIC, until 15 or so years later, FPGAs were big enough to take the logic and the resolution of registers needed without costing a foreign holiday each. Now, just program an Arduino or Spartan.